# Kriging simulation using ff package

Tags: r, ff, gstat, ffbase

I'm trying to understand the way I can use the ff package to overcome the error

```
"Error: cannot allocate vector of size 1.1 Mb"
```

while using kriging/ gaussian simulation. I don't know how to change the input data. Is there any idea to help me do that?

I'm using the gstat package to perform the simulation as follows:

```
library(sp)
data(meuse)
coordinates(meuse) = ~x+y
data(meuse.grid)
gridded(meuse.grid) = ~x+y
m <- vgm(.59, "Sph", 874, .04)
# ordinary kriging:
x <- krige(log(zinc)~1, meuse, meuse.grid, model = m, nsim=1000)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Gaussian simulation you need to set the neighbourhood size to some value, otherwise the memory consumption grows unlimited. You can do this e.g. by setting `nmax=50`, so the 50 nearest observed (or simulated) values are used as conditioning data.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, I set nmax=16 and received that error.