# Is Monte Carlo sampling in gstat: sequential Gaussian Simulation duplicitous?

Tags: r, montecarlo, kriging, gstat

How can I control over sampling in sequential Gaussian simulation?

For example in the following code, how can I guarantee that the Monte Carlo samples are not duplicitous?

```
library(sp)
library(gstat)

data(meuse)
coordinates(meuse) = ~x+y
data(meuse.grid)
gridded(meuse.grid) = ~x+y
m <- vgm(.59, "Sph", 874, .04)
# ordinary kriging:
x <- krige(zinc~1, meuse, meuse.grid, model = m, nsim=10, debug.level=-1)
```

I know that the default setting in sample function, is "replace = FALSE" and not to replace the generated samples. Is SGS the same?

Comment: Is the last line of your code supposed to run for minutes?

Comment: It is running for about five minutes on my machine, still not done.

Comment: Please run in the debug mode to see the progress. I edited the code.

Comment: Sorry @LAP I ran it again and faced a significant runtime. I'm sure that I could run this case for less than a minute. But now! I'm really confused!

Comment: Well, It's been running for nearly 20 Minutes and I've made it to 69% progress. And my machine is not too shabby :) As general advice, the probability of drawing the exact same full sequence from a sample of 155 observations is theoretically zero.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48520861/kriging-simulation-using-ff-package/48563536?noredirect=1#comment84192427_48563536

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kriging simulation using ff package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48520861/kriging-simulation-using-ff-package)